# Ubuntu 18 touchpad not working properly

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cursor

My touchpad is not working properly on Ubuntu 18. I can left-click on buttons etc, but the cursor won't move.

This is the result of my `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                  id=2     [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4     [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Touchpad    id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver             id=15    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver             id=17    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                 id=3     [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard       id=5     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                      id=6     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                         id=7     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                         id=8     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                      id=9     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                      id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam              id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      id=13    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                  id=14    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver             id=16    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: It may help others if you give the make and model of the laptop

Answer (score 0):

Press f2 on startup go into bios, go to "main", go down to "touchpad" and hit enter, change from "advanced" to "basic" hit f10 to save and reboot. Seems to be a setting that changes itself if you let your battery die, like legacy boot mode.

Comment: What device did this work for? Firmware varies a lot

Answer (score -1):

Check whether `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is install or not?

```
apt list --installed | grep xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

If it is missing, install it by invoking this command

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Now, reboot or logout your pc, it should fix your problem. And if you want tweak your mouse emulation configuration use `gnome-tweak`.

Comment: `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed